# Select items from an input that do not exist in the database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This query is a subset of a large query, where I'm `OUTER APPLY`'ing a bunch of values, to filter out results later

I've got some data:

```
Table: Items
        ID  |   Material   |  Form
    ----------------------------------
        1   |   Aluminium  |  Sheets
       ------------------------------
        1   | Carbon Steel |  Bars
       ------------------------------
        2   |   Aluminium  |  Bars
```

I want to find the matching IDs, that satisfy a given input. The input can be in one of three forms, and can have one or many rows. When an input has multiple rows, the item must satisfy ALL rows. Examples of input are given below:

```
@Input type 1: (just a material, one or multiple allowed)    
    Material     |  Form
    -------------------
    Aluminium    |  NULL

@Input type 2: (material and a form, one or multiple allowed)   
    Material     |  Form
    -------------------
    Aluminium    |  Sheets

@Input type 3: (one or more material and form, with one or more materials)  
    Material     |  Form
    -------------------
    Aluminium    |  Sheets
    Carbon Steel |  NULL
```

I've written a query that can handle input type 1 and a query for input type 2, but I need to combine them, and be able to handle input type 3.

Query for Input Type 1:

```
Select *
From table

OUTER APPLY(
  SELECT top(1) i.Material
  FROM @Input i --Input type 1
  WHERE i.Material NOT IN
    (SELECT items.Material
    FROM Items
    WHERE items.id = table.id)
)MaterailCondition

--this makes sure that there isn't anything selected that does not match Material
WHERE MaterialCondition.Material IS NULL
```

Query for Input Type 2:

```
Select *
From table

OUTER APPLY(
  SELECT top(1) i.Material, i.Form
  FROM @Input i --Input type 1
  WHERE i.Material NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT *
    FROM Items
    WHERE items.id = table.id
    AND items.Material = i.Material
    AND items.Form = i.Form)
)MaterailCondition

--this makes sure that there isn't anything selected that does not match Material
WHERE MaterialCondition.Form IS NULL
```

**Again, at this point, I need to be able to**

- Combine the queries into the same outer apply block
- Accomodate Input Type 3

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Also, if I can explain anything, or be any clearer about any aspect of this, please let me know. I tried to keep it as short and focused as possible.

**EDIT**

Here would be the desired output from the query

```
ID  |  Name      |  MaterialCondition.Material
-------------------------------------------
23  | Some Item  |  (any text, such as 'Carbon Steel') <-- This is not a match
12  | Other Item |  NULL                               <-- This IS a match

--(the where clause will filter these out, by saying)
WHERE MaterialCondition.Material IS NULL
```

So just ID number 12 is returned:

```
ID  |  Name      |  MaterialCondition.Material
-------------------------------------------
12  | Other Item |  NULL
```

Comment: For combining both queries use `UNION ALL`

Comment: @JonH - I don't think I can `UNION ALL`, because I need to have one `OUTER APPLY` statement accomodating the multiple conditions, so if I did a `UNION ALL` within the `OUTER APPLY`, the number of columns wouldn't match up properly. If you can think of a good way around the number of columns, I'm open!

Comment: What should be the final output for the all combined queries?

Comment: @SQL - does my edit help? or can i clear anything up further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I've gotten to a state that functions, like this:

```
Select *
From table
OUTER APPLY(  
 SELECT top(1) i.Material  
 FROM @Input i --Input type 1  
 WHERE i.Material NOT IN    
  (SELECT items.Material    
  FROM Items    
  WHERE items.id = table.id)
)MaterailCondition

OUTER APPLY(  
 SELECT top(1) i.Material, i.Form  
 FROM @Input i --Input type 1  
 WHERE i.Material NOT EXISTS    
  (SELECT *    
  FROM Items    
  WHERE items.id = table.id    
  AND items.Material = i.Material    
  AND items.Form = i.Form)
)MaterailCondition2

--this makes sure that there isn't anything selected that does not match Material
WHERE MaterialCondition.Material IS NULL AND MaterialCondition2.Form IS NULL
```

This will work properly, and I've got an outer apply for input type 1 and input type 2, then the outer applys will take care of their respective parts of input type 3. I guess I was just hoping to contain this logic inside of one `OUTER APPLY`